# I create json, but it doesnt show up correctly

Tags: ruby, json

I dont know if this is a ruby problem or not, but I am creating some json from a hash with ruby.  I am using the `json` library to create this json from a hash.  Here is the code I use to convert the hash to json:

```
advanced = {}
advanced.compare_by_identity
..Add stuff to hash
File.open('advanced.json', 'w') { |f|
  f.write(advanced.to_json)
}
```

Here is my output:

```
{
    "HUMANA": {
        "name": "HUMANA",
        "id": "61101",
        "st": [
            "AK",
            "AL",
            "AR",
            "AZ",
            "CA",
            "CO",
            "CT",
            "DE",
            "FL",
            "GA",
            "HI",
            "IA",
            "ID",
            "IL",
            "IN",
            "KS",
            "KY",
            "LA",
            "MA",
            "MD",
            "ME",
            "MI",
            "MN",
            "MO",
            "MS",
            "MT",
            "NC",
            "ND",
            "NE",
            "NH",
            "NJ",
            "NM",
            "NV",
            "NY",
            "OH",
            "OK",
            "OR",
            "PA",
            "RI",
            "SC",
            "SD",
            "TN",
            "TX",
            "UT",
            "VA",
            "VT",
            "WA",
            "WI",
            "WV    ",
            "WY"
        ],
        "gov": "N",
        "wc": "N",
        "enr": "N",
        "aac": false,
        "txns": {
            "Real-Time": [
                "276"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

There are 3 entries in the json, but when I drop it into a `printpretty`, it only shows me one entry.  What could be the cause of this?

Comment: can you include the code you are using to convert the hash to json as well as the original hash?

Comment: whoever edited my question removed the issue altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that json cannot have duplicate keys.